# Adobe CS5 Mac iOS High Sierra 10.13.6 Just stopped working! Help

Tags: high-sierra, crash, adobe

My Gear:
iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015)
Processor: 3.2 GHz Intel Core i5
Memory: 16 GB 1867 MHz DDR3
Graphics Card: AMD Radeon R9 M380 2048 MB

iOS: High Sierra 10.13.6

Preferences: The programs that are problematic are enabled. Only Photoshop works.

Problem:
I have been running CS5 for quite a few years now, relatively trouble free other than some minor quirks.

Primarily, I use Photoshop, Illustrator, Acrobat Pro, InDesign.

Yesterday, everything but Photoshop all suddenly came to a crashing halt.  Cannot start up the programs again.  A long time ago, I turned off all auto updates.

What changed? 
Why, out of the blue, would all these Adobe programs just stop working?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: CS5 really isn't supported beyond El Capitan. People have managed to keep it limping along until Sierra, but High Sierra's APFS & lack of support for legacy Java is really going to make life difficult. Maybe see https://blog.conradchavez.com/2017/09/25/macos-10-13-high-sierra-will-adobe-software-work/#preCC for some hints, but be prepared to either roll back your OS, or invest in current versions.

Comment: Thank you for that link. Greatly appreciated. I am currently waiting a Cable from Amazon so I can try a recovery from my MacBook Pro. I used to be an Authorized Apple Dealer and Adobe reseller. I cannot stand, with every breath in my body, Adobe. Garbage company based on that experience. Classic, greedy sleazy  big company. They will never get another dime from me. If I have to, will regress OS. It worked fine for years, just stopped out of the blue. Hoping to reinstall older backup, may set it right again.

Comment: Here is the kicker .... APPLE, in their infinite wisdom.... has made it virtually impossible to roll back! I will be honest, I am totally disgusted by APPLE!  Why? I purchased their computer and I fully EXPECT THE RIGHT To CHOOSE WHICH OS I USE ESPECIALLY THE ONE I PURCHASED WITH THE SYSTEM!!!  Why do I have to struggle to make a boot disc of the system I was using?!?!?!!!!  I don’t need their support!  I don’t want their support!  I want to load MY OS OF CHOICE I PAID FOR WHEN I PURCHASED THE SYSTEM!!!  End of story!

Comment: Golden rules before any major update: 1) make sure all your mission critical software will run on it & 2) Make sure you can get back to the old OS if you find a blocker [this will involve a clone as well as Time Machine, in case of emergency]. You cannot blame Apple for your lack of foresight. Sorry, but life just doesn't work that way.

Comment: Yes, I can blame APPLE.

Comment: 1) Regardless of what happened, I purchased my system with High Ierra.

Comment: 2015 iMac came with El Capitan - & would back then have run CS5, just about OK. Not Apple's fault you're trying to get software to limp along that was last updated in 2011.

Comment: 2) the system I purchased it with is REGISTERED with Apple. 3) If I want my system RETURNED to that OS, that is my prerogative to determine whether I will or not. 4) APPLE should give me what I am a registered owner of. Period. 5) Up until 2017, you could get the OS with the installer. After, they crippled it. Why? AND, read the problem... I did not initiate the upgrade, it installed itself over night. I know full well what to do in an upgrade situation.

Comment: 1) Major OS upgrades do not happen on their own. Never have, never will. 2) Rather than ranting in here, which is doing little except keeping me amused, why not post a question on Ask Different, 'How do I get back to El Capitan?'

Answer (score 1):

After paying $1800 at the time for Adobe Creative Suite CS5, I too have no desire to go to a cloud based "pay for play" software, especially during these uncertain financial times.

Have you tried having two hard drives which contain two different operating systems on them?

I have Mac OS 10.8.5 on one hard drive so that I can used Steinberg's Cubase version 6, and I have MAC OS 10.13.6 Hign Sierra on a my main hard drive - I just switch to my "downgrade" hard drive and keep working...and you can access both drives from the menu like normal.

That was my saving grace!  I can still use Photoshop on 10.13.6, but it won't let me run Adobe Premiere CS5.

Sadly, in all my Mac years no one ever told me I could do that.  It would've saved me a lot of upgrade money when a new OS didn't work with my audio software (especially WAVES plugins which I paid lots of money for and it became obsolete, since WAVES too is on a cloud-based-pay-to-play model)

Hope this helps.

Comment: You could also use a Virtual Machine: an OS running as an app inside your current OS.